# How do I disable pasting when clicking the middle mouse button/wheel?

Tags: mouse, mouse-wheel

I use the mouse wheel a lot to scroll up and down in my documents and files. Having moved from Windows, I didn't realise that the middle mouse button/wheel, when clicked, pastes highlighted text where the mouse is pointing.

I've been hit with this several time, where my scripts have failed because of a paste that takes me a while to discover.

After several attempts at disabling the middle mouse button, I succeedded with:

`xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 25 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"`

I found this on this [site](http://jaredrobinson.com/blog/howto-disable-middle-mouse-paste-in-linux/), which also states how to persist it.

The problem with this feature, is that I rely on other elements of clicking the middle mouse button such as opening links in a new tab or closing a tab in my browser (to name 2 of a few).

It is annoying me that I have lost these functions. How can I disable pasting but keep all the other uses of middle mouse button clicking?

*** Please note I am reasonably new to Ubuntu and Linux and have also read about patching the kernel, but I don't feel confident doing this!! ***