# Can I stop my mouse from [accidentally] pasting text to irc channels?

Tags: 12.10, xubuntu, irc

**Xubuntu 12.10**
I do not mind that text is occasionally pasted when I can simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> most things, or simply erase the text. Currently however, when I ssh to a server running my irc client, clicking the mouse3 button on the window will more than likely paste text in a very unforgiving manner! That means I can't take back whatever my mouse decided to [accidentally] tell the other irc members (yes it is the mouse's fault).

Therefore: Can I disable middle-mouse pasting to a terminal window without losing an arm or a leg? Perhaps this is too localized, but I am sure plenty of people have had the same issue with irc and have empathy for this issue :)

Comment: I would consider middle-button pasting a feature, not a bug :)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94848/how-do-i-disable-pasting-when-clicking-the-middle-mouse-button-wheel

Comment: @ayke I saw that question before I asked, and I think he has the same trouble as me. I do not want to disable middle-mouse. I just want to be able to customize ubuntu such that if I use that mouse3 button on a terminal, it ignores the command.

Comment: @Sergey Although I consider it a feature, I also consider it an issue that the feature is not customizable, I do not consider it a 'bug'